# Index.html file not found on Firefox after building dev version of Polkadot.js extension

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot-js-extension, browser-extension

When I start the development version of the [Polkadot.js extension](https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension) on Firefox after installing it, I'm getting the error: File not found. Firefox cannot find the file on moz-extension://.../index.html.

Before installing I build the extension using yarn build as described in the README.md file. Starting the extension on Google Chrome does work.

How to start a development version of the extension on Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by loading the index.html file instead of the manifest.json file. I created a [pull request](https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension/pull/1156).